# Dialog en Jquery 3.3

Tags: jquery

Hola: Estoy abriendo un dialog en jquery 1.11.1

```
$("#dialog_edit_settings").dialog({
            title: 'editar ajustes'
        });

$("#dialog_edit_settings").dialog("open");
```

Se abre correctamente.

Ahora, posteriormente, necesito usar jquery 3.3 para usar otros controles y al incluirlo me dice que

> dialog is not a function()

¿Cómo se abre un dialog con la version 3.3?
Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: los dialog forman parte de jQuey-UI. Asegurate de que lo tienes incluido en tu página. Si no es así, lo tienes aqui: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Hola Pablo: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Las lineas incluidas son: <script src./r="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>                                                                                                  Y esto hace que me de el error dialog is not a function

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

Comment: Prueba a cargar las últimas versiones a través de los CDN. Primero jquery y luego jquery-ui

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

También fijate que el error te lo está dando en la version 3.1.1 y no en la que has puesto (1.11.1)

Comment: Gracias a todos.                                                                                                      A mi se me ha resuelto incluyendo                                                                 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>